# Synchronous Serial over Internet

Tags: serial, signal-processing, synchronous, serial-bus

I have a portable diagnostics tool which communicates with an electronic appliance using which I believe is Synchronous Serial Interface (SSI).

I'm looking for a way that I can extend the range of this tool over LAN so that a the appliance can be connected to PC1, and the tool to PC2, and software running on both PCs bridge the SSI over LAN.

This is a circuit diagram showing the tool connection to the appliance board with inputs labelled SCK, CLK, RXD, TXD, VCC, GND: (I have already established that the tool can be powered directly by applying 5V between VCC and GND).

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: Can the tool and other thing use an external clock for the serial?

Comment: @AlexanderM I wouldn't know. How would I test this?

Comment: I don't know. I'll post an answer that assumes yes

Comment: This probably will not work via simple translation/encapsulation, as the master is going to expect the data read back to be synchronized to its clock, which is not something you will have sufficient time to achieve when Internet delays are inserted.  Rather, you would have to understand the protocol enough to emulate one device - basically, you very nearly approach the point where you should just design your own system.  Or co-locate the PC with the instrument and use screen sharing type software to run it remotely.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that's an answer

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's a good idea however in this case it's not practical to co-locate the tool with the appliance and control the tool remotely as I need to use the one tool to control multiple appliances remotely.

Comment: Perhaps you should figure out what the tool does and come up with a cheaper implementation based on inexpensive Ethernet-enabled MCU boards you can distribute.   Consider investigating its operation with an fx2-based USB logic analyzer.

Comment: Unfortunately it's beyond my capability to reverse engineer this tool. Is there any possibility of bodging a solution together with multiple RS232 or RS422 adapters (i.e. TxD/RxD & SCK/CLK on different adapters)? What would Macgyver do?

Answer (score -1):

*Assuming both devices can use an external clock*

Use a Arduino Leonardo or a teensy or something similar to generate an external clock for both devices to clock in and out the serial. Now it is a matter of writing software. Inspired by connecting two gameboys over the net for Pokemon trades in red and blue; the game boy can go at a link speed of 1bit/mo on an external clock.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I can see the merit in this as there are bound to be games adapted to work this was as you have mentioned. I was hoping there would be a straightforward off the shelf way to achieve this using some sort of RS422 adapters..